# Text is really unsharp

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

When I create a 2D text, its really unsharp.
Doyou guys might know what to do?
p.s I mean the 'ripples' around the text.

High res image: http://gyazo.com/1a80c0ed88b1d54098279af4985ec060

Lower res preview:
[image]

Comment: That appears about as sharp as one can get on a screen.

Answer (score 2):

Your screen is made up of small diodes of light which are called pixels. These pixels are squares lined up in rows on top of each other.

The reason you see that pixilation on the edge of the letters is because the computer is trying to represent a perfect curve with squares. It can only get as accurate as the resolution of your screen.

If you were to zoom in further on your lettering, you might notice that the pixelation would get less and less intense (if your artwork is vectorized) or more intense (if your artwork is rasterized).

If you were to print your work, and the dpi of the image were high enough, you shouldn't see any pixilation as printers usually print at 300 dpi (dots per inch) which the human eye can't distinguish between two dots without a magnifying class, so your text should appear as smooth curves.

Comment: The pixelation would remain the same on a vector image as the pixelation is caused by the hardware device itself (the screen).

Comment: But, the curve would seem to be getting straighter as you zoomed in.